# Fantasy manga/manhwa about a young guy who comes to a young noble girl's house to teach her magic

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

I want to know the name of this manga/manhwa that I had recently remember reading. It's about this young guy who comes to teach this young noble daughter magic at their house. I also remember early on into this, the noble girl's maid also wants the young guy to teach them as well.

I think it was mostly black and white and, if I remember it correctly, I think the noble girl had white hair.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: I cant remember I think it was mostly black and white and If I remember it correctly I think the noble girl had white hair.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely *[Private Tutor to the Duke’s Daughter](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/private-tutor-to-the-dukes-daughter)*.

> After failing the final exam for his dream job at the royal court, promising young sorcerer Allen wants nothing more than to retreat to a simple life in the countryside. Unfortunately for him, he can’t even afford the train fare! His only solution is to get a job, but his one lead is anything but modest—**Duke Howard, one of the kingdom’s most powerful nobles, needs a private tutor for his daughter Tina**. Despite her academic brilliance, Tina is incapable of casting even a single spell.

[image: Cover]

The synopsis covers much of the question, and the events of the first chapter. The protagonist is a young man and goes to a noble's estate to act as a tutor for the Duke's young daughter. She has light blue hair, which does look mostly white in a black&white manga.

In the second chapter, her maid also becomes a student, as she wishes to attend the academy with her mistress.

[image: Maid asks to become a student]